# how to reset emacs HOME directory

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am shifting to EMACS for cpp development in **windows**. Yes ..

But i was reading a tutorial about setting it up and set the `HOME` in path variable to `C:\ABC;`

old habit from putting a `;` at the end of `PATH`.

so now emacs created this `ABC;` directory and everything works.

but it does not look good to me.. so **i reset the `HOME` environment variable to `C:\ABC`** and deleted the `ABC;` folder.

but instead of emacs creating `ABC` it starts complaining about no `ABC;` which is bad.

I looked into the Registry and but did not found any `GNU` key.
I also looked into `%appdata` but no emacs folder there.

How can i reset the `HOME` directory in emacs again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just cite the Info file node `(emacs)Top > Emacs Invocation > Environment > MS-Windows Registry`. I think the third section is the most relevant for you.

Did you any customization yet? If so, try `emacs -Q` to try emacs without customization.

```
C.4.3 The MS-Windows System Registry
------------------------------------

On MS-Windows, the installation program `addpm.exe' adds values for
`emacs_dir', `EMACSLOADPATH', `EMACSDATA', `EMACSPATH', `EMACSDOC',
`SHELL' and `TERM' to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' section of the system
registry, under `/Software/GNU/Emacs'.  It does this because there is
no standard place to set environment variables across different
versions of Windows.  Running `addpm.exe' is no longer strictly
necessary in recent versions of Emacs, but if you are upgrading from an
older version, running `addpm.exe' ensures that you do not have older
registry entries from a previous installation, which may not be
compatible with the latest version of Emacs.

   When Emacs starts, as well as checking the environment, it also
checks the System Registry for those variables and for `HOME', `LANG'
and `PRELOAD_WINSOCK'.

   To determine the value of those variables, Emacs goes through the
following procedure.  First, the environment is checked.  If the
variable is not found there, Emacs looks for registry keys by that name
under `/Software/GNU/Emacs'; first in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER' section
of the registry, and if not found there, in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
section.  Finally, if Emacs still cannot determine the values,
compiled-in defaults are used.

   In addition to the environment variables above, you can also add many
of the settings which on X belong in the `.Xdefaults' file (*note X
Resources::) to the `/Software/GNU/Emacs' registry key.
```

Note, that if you set the `HOME` variable in the environment it will not appear in the registry. You must reset it in the environment. 
The relevant section of the info files about that:

```
You can override this default value of `HOME' by explicitly setting
the environment variable `HOME' to point to any directory on your
system.  `HOME' can be set either from the command shell prompt or from
`Properties' dialog of `My Computer'.
```

Comment: I have changed the HOME environment variable before asking question, but that did not worked. SHould i restart once.

Comment: @AshishNegi If you want to check whether `HOME` is the problem you could try from `cmd.exe`. Example: 1st input: `set HOME=c:\ABC` 2nd input: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\emacs-24.3\bin\runemacs.exe" -Q` In emacs you could type `M-x getenv<ENTER>HOME<ENTER>`

Comment: Thanks i was doing something bad.. starting runemacs from the old command prompt. which had old settings.. windows...